# Sequence 1:k - is there an element of sequence in the list of lists? (in R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function. I have two vectors and variable k(number), e.g. : vector1 <- c(1,2), vector2 <- c(2,4) and k=5. I'm making three sequences: one made of the first elements of vectors (1:2), second one for the next elements of vectors (2:4) - I managed to do this by using mapply:

```
mapply(seq, vector1, vector2, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

and the third sequence 1:k, and I'm having trouble with finding if there is an element of the third sequence in second one or in the third sequence, and if it is my function should return TRUE for this element, e.g. output should be something like this:

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

(TRUE - 1 is in 1:2, TRUE - 2 is in 1:2 (and also 2:4),TRUE - 3 is in 2:4,TRUE - 4 is in 2:4 and FALSE- 5 isn't in 1:2 and it isn't in 2:4)

I tried to use apply(apply) with isTRUE, element%in%sequences[i]. Is there a simple solution without the need of using a loop? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, we need to `Reduce` into a vector after doing the comparison

```
Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y) seq_len(k) %in% x:y , vector1, vector2))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(Map(`:`, vector1, vector2), `%in%`, x = seq_len(k)))
```